# How to compare two string where the order of the elements no matter

Tags: string, python-2.7, compare

I'm looking for some function where I can compare two string with the exception that the order of the elements no matter. E.g.:

```
'abc' == 'bca'
True
```

Does python have some built-in function like this?

Comment: Does the number of occurrences of each letter have to match as well? A `set` comparison could be useful here (`set('abc') == set('bca')`) but not if recurrence matters.

Comment: what about `aabc` and `bac`?

Comment: aabc Vs bac matter and it should be false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in python are iterables that return the characters in the string. Like any iterable, they can be wrapped with `sorted`. If you compare those wrappers, you'd essentially be comparing whether both strings have the same characters in them, regardless of their original order:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> t = 'bca'
>>> s == t
False
>>> sorted(s) == sorted(t)
True
```

Comment: If duplicates matter, this is a more effective solution than mine.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

6For smaller strings you could call sorted on both strings:

```
def is_equal(a, b):
    return len(a) == len(b) and sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

For `sorted(a) == sorted(b)` to be True, both strings must be the same length and have the same  characters:

Or use a `Counter` dict to count the frequencies if the string lengths are the same:

```
 from collections import Counter


def is_equal(a, b):
    return len(a) == len(b) and Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```

If the strings are different lengths then they cannot be equal, if they are all the chars from a have to be in b and the frequency has to be the same. The solution is `O(n)` as opposed to `O(n log n)` calling sorted